# Android App not connecting not updating MYSQL table via Web Service on Apache, Axis2, Mysql, Tomcat, Eclipse

Tags: android, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, apache-axis

I'm using pasted tutorial code to connect to a MySQL database and simply post to a table. The Android app is returning the text correctly from the data fields and I'm seeing the traffic over port 8080 into Apache. However, when I sniff traffic going into the Database interface over 3306, I see nothing and count(*) in Mysql returns 0 entries. How can I check to see what JDBC is doing with the data?

### Java Web Service

```
package com.retailer.ws;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet; 
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class RetailerWS {
public String customerData(){
String customerInfo = "";
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306        /login","root","password");
//Find customer information where the customer ID is maximum
PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(name,password)     VALUES('"+userName+"','"+userPassword"')");
 ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

while(result.next()){
customerInfo = customerInfo + result.getString("name") + "&" +         result.getString("C_ID") + "&"+result.getString("address") + "&"+result.getString("email");

}
}

catch(Exception exc){
 System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
 }

return customerInfo;
}
```

### }

### Java Web Service Client

```
 package com.userdata.ws;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
  import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidMySQLClientActivity extends Activity{
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.chathura.com";
private final String URL = "http://host:8080/First/services/Users?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.chathura.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            insertValues();
        }
    });
}

public void insertValues(){
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

 //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//Define value for fname variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for userPassword variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("userPassword");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new         SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        result.setText(response.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    }

   }
```